# $$array[0] returns array name letter and not array value

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to use the first value of a dynamically created array but I get the first letter of the array name instead.

```
$log = "dets_".$id;
$$log = array();
while ($c = mysql_fetch_assoc($cuenta)) { array_push($$log,$c['id'].'::'.$c['fecha']); }
```

When I print $$log I get something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 124::2017-04-07 [1] => 119::2017-04-07 [2] => 118::2017-04-05 )
```

But when I try to access the first key:

```
echo $$log[0];
```

I get "$d" and not "124::2017-04-07". I also tried $log[0] and get "d".
Thank you.

Comment: Any time you find yourself doing dynamic variables, you're probably doing it wrong. Use an associative array instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could access the first element by somewhat tricky expression:

```
var_dump (${${'log'}}[0]);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

**A bit of explanation Taken from [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)**

> In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an
>   ambiguity problem. That is, if you write `$$a[1]` then the parser needs
>   to know if you meant to use `$a[1]` as a variable, or if you wanted `$$a`
>   as the variable and then the `[1]` index from that variable. The syntax
>   for resolving this ambiguity is: `${$a[1]}` for the first case and
>   `${$a}[1]` for the second.

Comment: Thank you very much, Indeed it worked even  setting the variable
    
with    $test = ${${'log'}}[0];


Any explanation why this syntax is needed (I would like to understand)? 
Thanks again! 

(tried to upvote your answer but I ain't got the necessary rep, sorry)

Comment: See my update. And you don't upvote an answer. You accept an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, akond!